# Wordpress shortcode for a section Template

Tags: shortcode

I have made a Section Template called section-bachelorscholarships.php in the Folder frontpage in the Theme Folder and I have put this Code

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php  $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'grants ' ,
        'scholarship_degree'=> 'bachelor',
        'status'=>'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'expired',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => array( 'expired' ),
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',)),);
    $q    = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <div class="row">
      <?php while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding: 0px;">  
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  >
                <div class="card">
                <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'thumbnail' ); ?>
                <img  class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $url ?>" />    
                <div class="card-body">
                     <p class="card-title"><?php the_title();?> </p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                              <div class="text-muted">
                                 <p><?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'funding-scholarship');
                                      if ($terms) {$out = array( 'name'=>' ' );              
                                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                              $out[] = '<a class="text-muted' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( 
                                              $term->slug, 'funding-scholarship') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';}
                                              echo join( ', ', $out ); }?></small></p> 
                                        </p>
                                      </div>  
                                    </div>  
                                  </div>
                                </div> 
                          <?php endwhile; ?>
                          </div>
                          <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                          <?php endwhile; ?> 
                      </div>
```

then I put this code into the Function.php

```php
         function my_master_shortcode( $attr ) {
         ob_start();
         get_template_part('frontpage/section', 'bachelorscholarships');
         return ob_get_clean();
           }
         add_shortcode( 'mastergrants', 'my_master_shortcode' );
```

My problem is when I load the Front page to see the Update is still loading without End and getting stuck with it, Any Help

Comment: Why is your `posts_per_page` set to negative 4? I fixed the code block formatting in your question so it's viewable, but can you indent your code correctly? It's extremely difficult to read

Comment: Sorry, This is my first time I write a quistion here and I really do not know how to deal with stack Exchange Forms. I just need to display four Posts in this part of the Template that Why I made it -4 as I know, Should I turn it off to jus 4 ?

Comment: Yes, should just be `4`.

Comment: The only case I have seen using a negative number for `posts_per_page` is using `-1` which will return all posts that match the query.

Comment: I have tried to put it 'posts_per_page'=> 4, but is still have the Problem which I have

Comment: You have an extra space in the code `'post_type'=> 'grants ' ,` after the `s` in `grants`.  Not sure if that is the cause but worth a check?

Comment: No, It is not . It is still loading without ending the page and repeat it self

Comment: in which post or post_type or page do you actually enter the shortcode `[mastergrants]`? also, you refer to a template 'section-countriesinfo.php' but you use 'frontpage/section', 'bachelorscholarships'.

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks for Your Answer, It was a printing mistake , I have edite the section name but it still not solved . I have made a section name called from the begining called section.bachelorscholarships.php and I inserted the Shortcode [mastergrants] into the Front page Template.

Comment: Note that even if it doesn't fix this problem, setting that value to negative numbers is not a good idea, it should be `4` not `-4`. Also, you have a tax query with `NOT IN`, that parameter is **extremely slow/expensive**, avoid it. It would be much, much, faster to also have a `not_expired` term. I've a strong suspicion your problem is that your query is so expensive it takes too long to run before the timeout for generating the page

Comment: Thanks alot , I have to use it the Exiration Exclution taxonomy term that I do not want to use a blugin to display my posts and this is the Only Solution I have found to do it.and for the -4 I have Edited it thank you , but still look for a solution to make it in a good way without slowing the Page load , It is just four Posts which I need to display

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Solution with another Code but still not know what was the Problem with the First Code . It is solved . the Code which I will use will be :

```
               <div class="card-deck">
               <?php 
               // the query  
               $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                  'post_type'=>'grants',
                                  'scholarship_degree'=> 'bachelor',
                                  'post_status'=>'publish',
                                  'posts_per_page'=>  4,
                                  'tax_query' => array(array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'expired',
                                     'field'    => 'slug',
                                     'terms'    => array( 'expired' ),
                                     'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                                    )),
                                )); 
            ?> 
            <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                  <!-- the loop -->
               <div class="row">           
                    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
                       <div class="col-sm-3" > 
                           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                             <div class="card">
                              <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), ' ' ); ?>
                              <img  class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $url ?>" /> 
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-title"><?php the_title();?> </p>
                                         </a>
                                          <p class="card-text">
                                        <div class="text-muted">
                                    <p><?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'funding-scholarship');
                                              if ($terms) {
                                              $out = array(
                                              'name'=>' 
                                                  <svg class="bi bi-bookmark" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"                                                                          fill="black"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                   <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 12l5 3V3a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12l5-3zm-4 1.234l4-2.4 4 2.4V3a1 1 0 00-1-1H5a1 1 0 00-1 1v10.234z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                                  </svg> تمويل المنحة     ');
                                  foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                  $out[] = '<a class="text-muted' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'funding-scholarship') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';}
                                   echo join( ', ', $out ); }?></small></p> 
                          </div>  
                      </div>  
                  </div>
               </div>  
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
                  <!-- end of the loop -->
                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                  <?php else : ?>
                  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p> 
                  <?php endif; ?>  
                  </div>  
                  </div>
```

```
          AND THE SHORTCODE WHICH I WILL USE :
```

```
          function my_bachelor_shortcode( $attr ) {
                       ob_start();
                       get_template_part('frontpage/section', 'bachelorscholarships');
                      return ob_get_clean();
          }
          add_shortcode( 'bachelorgrantslist', 'my_bachelor_shortcode' );
```